# problem about NPAPI plugin ...my browser was blocked !

Tags: plugins, browser, callback, npapi

1. Tools I use :
   Browser:  firefox 3.6.17   and   Google Chrome
   Interface:NPAPI
2. My question:
   I want to callback  a  Javascript function from my NPAPI plugin by calling NPN_invokeDefault after finish to execute "Exec_func"  , but it takes secends  to execute "Exec_func" ( the browser wait for its return!).  for this , I have to create a child thread to execute it ,otherwise the browser will be blocked !
   if  I do this , the browser firefox still  be blocked like doing nothing , and the browser google chrome will tell me : return error  after  execute NPN_invokeDefault   .

   Regards

addition:

how do i async callback javascript funcs from plugins ,meantime the browser won't be blocked

thanks

Regards

Answer (score 0):

The [NPAPI documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Gecko_Plugin_API_Reference/Browser_Side_Plug-in_API) is very clear about the fact that you cannot call NPN_* functions from any thread but the main thread.

Comment: thank you ... Smorgan ..however , i have used NPN_PluginThreadAsyncCall to  call NPN_functions ,i heard from other guys  
by  NPN_PluginThreadAsyncCall, i can call NPN_functions from other child thread.